# Make freestyle draw on curved edges

Tags: edit-mode, eevee-render-engine, freestyle

I have a lego figure I ham trying to draw freestyle lines on (eevee)  and where the top of his body meets the front there is no line because it is curved but I want to put a freestyle line there [image: no lines!]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just edit the crease angle property so it detects the higher angles.

[image]

Comment: thanx daddi jimbo